# Meta Box Oxygen Builder Query Custom Post Type based on current date

Tags: php, metadata, meta-boxes, meta-query, oxygenbuilder

I created a custom post type using Meta Box called "event". I wanted to hide posts based on event-end-date if it's in the past.

Below is how I set up the custom query in Oxygen Builder, it shows posts in the order of the event start date. How should I setup the meta query to hide events in the past? I am having issues to compare the event-end-date or event-start-date with the current date. I think it's about the format. Thanks.

[image]